# Excluding first two categories in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So I want to exclude the first two categories in the array, I want it to be dynamic so whether someone changes the orderby or parent, the exclude parameter will always exclude the first two in the array.

I've searched long and far and can't seem to find any solution :(.

```
$args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'parent' => 46, 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'hide_empty' => 1, 'exclude' =>  ##first & second in array ## );

$categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 
echo '<li>
    <a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">
        <img src="' . z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id) . '" />
        <div class="info">
            <div class="vert-center">
                <h4 class="note-name">' . $category->cat_name . '</h4>
                <hr>
                <p class="note-descriptor">' . $category->category_description . '</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$categories = get_categories( $args );`

On this line above, you are holding an array of categories.
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9]

so if you unset it, it should work
`unset($categories[0]);`

**edit** you will also need `array_value` to fix the empty index

```
$newcat = array_values($categories);
```

before your foreach

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 
echo '<li>
    <a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">
        <img src="' . z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id) . '" />
        <div class="info">
            <div class="vert-center">
                <h4 class="note-name">' . $category->cat_name . '</h4>
                <hr>
                <p class="note-descriptor">' . $category->category_description . '</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>';
}
```